# Is there any way to get the name of a printer that used to be connected to a Windows computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, drivers, printer

I have Windows 8, and I used to have a printer connected to it. I loved it, but it broke, so now I'm trying to buy a new one, but I forgot to take down the model of it before it was thrown away. I remember having to install the drivers for it, so I'm hoping there is some way to retrieve it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

run at `cmd`:

```
findstr Class\=Printer %windir%\inf\oem*.inf
```

and see model at `[HP.NTAMD64]` section

Comment: Hmm... all I get is:
C:\WINDOWS\inf\oem24.inf:Class=Printer
C:\WINDOWS\inf\oem62.inf:Class=Printer
C:\WINDOWS\inf\oem71.inf:Class=Printer

Comment: Did you actually uninstall the driver? If not, and it's a low-cost HP printer, it may still be listed in Control Panel > Programs & Features.

Comment: @EGHDK see printer model name at oem24.inf oem62.inf oem71.inf

Comment: Oh? So actually look at those files? I will do that later tonight!

Answer (score 0):

Configuration screen -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers.
The printer should be there greyed out because it is not connected/offline.

A second method would be to go to Device Manager and look under the printer section. The driver should be listed there with the corresponding device name.

Comment: This was the first two things I tried with no luck. It is not listed under devices and printers, and it isn't in the device manager.

Comment: You could search your computer for anything HP related and see if there are any clues.